# Counting duplicates (not necessarily removing) in an array in O(n)

Tags: algorithm, big-o

This is for an assignment, and is in psuedo-code.

I need to find how many integers in an array are unique, nothing else, but it has to be in O(n), preferably without hashing.

Thanks!

Comment: So, since this is for an assignment, what ideas do you have so far? Certainly you're not expecting us to just give you the answer to use as your own, yes?

Comment: I suppose I shouldn't.

The big problem was finding the kth largest element in the array, values are not restricted. I used partitioning along with a function for finding the median. for removing/counting the duplicates, I thought about using linear sorting, since I know the values on the left of the partition are smaller than the median, but I need O(n) worst case, then I thought about hashing but we haven't reached that yet.

Comment: @Mosho "linear sorting" - a mistake. there is linear search.

Comment: That's what they called it in the lecture, I think. Refers to Radix/Counting/Bucket sort.

Comment: Inserting/querying a hash table is O(n) worst-case, so even if hashing was allowed it wouldn't be useful :)

Comment: I had this as part of a homework assignment this year, except we had to do it within O(lg n), and provide two ways of doing it.  Are you sure it was O(n)?  Seems like hashing and a ridiculous lookup table would be the only ways.

Comment: @Precision: You can't even examine all of the numbers in O(lg n) operations.

Comment: @Daniel Stutzbach: Apologies, I mistyped.  O(n lg n).

Comment: "Preferably without hashing"? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this pseudo code?

```
array randomNumbers;
array unique;
int uniqueCount = 0;

for (i in randomNumbers) {

  unique[i] += 1;
  uniqueCount++; //count all here
  // and remove duplicities here
  if (unique[i] > 1) {
    uniqueCount--;
  }
}
return uniqueCount;
```

And the premis is, that undeclared unique[i] is 0

Comment: @Mosho: A similar technique can be used to [sort an array in O(n+k)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)

Comment: That's exactly what I originally had in mind, but it wasn't good enough.

Comment: @Moravec and if range is unsigned integer you are going to allocate 4 Gbs ?

Comment: @Andrey, the question wasn't about wasteful memory usage, but time complexity. Yes, I agree, unique would have to be a huge array, but it would meet the time complexity requirement.

Comment: @Andrey: @Silmaril89 answered. And we can't know how the array is implemented. And in the end you can use other data structure as List etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through each element in the array and keep track of the elements you see, when you see a duplicate, report it.

Also, depending on how you keep track of elements, it may or may not be O(n), but I'll leave that part up to you, you got to learn something at least.

Comment: OMG. and what is complexity of "keeping track"?

Comment: I think you mean some kind of hashing? That's what I thought about at least, but I don't think it is allowed.

Comment: I was actually, thinking something more like what Moravec posted, using a different array to "keep track". And @Andrey, you can keep track of the elements this way with no extra complexity.

Comment: @Silmaril89 - really? ok, i will be less sarcastic. O(n) means that you will do a constant time operation on each element. There is no way to check tracking of something in constant time. Except if you build hashmap before, but building hashmap has it's own complexity.

Comment: @Andrey, What is the complexity of Moravec's answer?

Comment: @Silmaril89 it is obviously O(n), BUT: 1) it is not general. it works only on numbers 2) it will work on small range of numbers otherwise the memory overhead will be enormous. it is not proper just mentioning keeping track of elements without specifying the way.

Comment: @Andrey, sure, but I don't think it's proper for someone to get the entire answer if it is for homework (they won't learn anything if they get the answer).  But, I agree with what you are saying. So, let's stop this useless argument and be friends!

Comment: @Silmaril89 agree :) i just got a feeling that you are giving wrong directions to younger generation